# How to capture data from a view, perform a calculation, and return the result back to the view?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, websocket, maui

**UPDATE 1:**

The `HoldingsValue` calculation works if I use a local `HoldingsAmount` value.  How do I get it to take the value from the xaml `HoldingsAmount` `Entry`?

View: TickerView.xaml

Added binding to the `text` property of the `entry` control:

```
<Entry Placeholder="Enter holdings"
    Text="{Binding Ticker.HoldingsAmount}"
    Keyboard="Numeric" />
```

Models: Tickers.cs

Added `HoldingsAmount` to the model:

```
namespace MVVMDemo2.MVVM.Models
{
    public class Ticker
    {
        public decimal HoldingsAmount { get; set; }
        public string AskPrice { get; set; }
        public string BidPrice { get; set; }
        public string HoldingsValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ViewModels: TickerViewModel.cs

```
using Binance.Net.Clients;
using Binance.Net.Objects;
using MVVMDemo2.MVVM.Models;
using PropertyChanged;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MVVMDemo2.MVVM.ViewModels
{
    [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
    public class TickerViewModel
    {
        public Ticker Ticker { get; set; }
        //public decimal HoldingsAmount { get; set; }

        public TickerViewModel()
        {
            var socketClient = new BinanceSocketClient(new BinanceSocketClientOptions { });

            socketClient.SpotStreams.SubscribeToBookTickerUpdatesAsync("BTCUSDT", data => {

                decimal HoldingsAmount = 2;

                Ticker = new Ticker
                {
                    AskPrice = $"${data.Data.BestAskPrice.ToString("N2")}",
                    BidPrice = $"${data.Data.BestBidPrice.ToString("N2")}",
                    HoldingsValue = (HoldingsAmount * data.Data.BestBidPrice).ToString()
                };

            });

            socketClient.UnsubscribeAllAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**ORIGINAL:**

I'm trying to learn MAUI and MVVM, but I can't seem to read a value from the XAML form to use with data from a WebSocket.

I currently have the following which works:

Views: TickerView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MVVMDemo2.MVVM.Views.TickerView"
             Title="TickerView">
    
    <VerticalStackLayout
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center">
        
        <Label 
            Text="Holdings"
            FontSize="25" />
        <Entry Placeholder="Enter holdings"
            BackgroundColor="Gray"
            Keyboard="Numeric" />
        
        <Label 
            Text="Ask price"
            FontSize="25" />
        <Label 
            Text="{Binding Ticker.AskPrice}"
            FontSize="50" />
        
        <Label
            Text="Bid price"
            FontSize="25" />
        <Label 
            Text="{Binding Ticker.BidPrice}"
            FontSize="50" />

        <Label 
            Text="Holdings value"
            FontSize="25" />
        <Label 
            Text="{Binding Ticker.HoldingsValue}"
            FontSize="50" />

    </VerticalStackLayout>
    
</ContentPage>
```

Views: TickerView.xaml.cs

```
using MVVMDemo2.MVVM.Models;
using MVVMDemo2.MVVM.ViewModels;

namespace MVVMDemo2.MVVM.Views;

public partial class TickerView : ContentPage
{
    public TickerView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new TickerViewModel();
    }
}
```

Models: Ticker.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MVVMDemo2.MVVM.Models
{
    public class Ticker
    {
        public string AskPrice { get; set; }
        public string BidPrice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ViewModels: TickerViewModel.cs

```
using Binance.Net.Clients;
using Binance.Net.Objects;
using MVVMDemo2.MVVM.Models;
using PropertyChanged;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MVVMDemo2.MVVM.ViewModels
{
    [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
    public class TickerViewModel
    {
        public Ticker Ticker { get; set; }
        public TickerViewModel()
        {
            var socketClient = new BinanceSocketClient(new BinanceSocketClientOptions { });

            socketClient.SpotStreams.SubscribeToBookTickerUpdatesAsync("BTCUSDT", data => {

                Ticker = new Ticker
                {
                    AskPrice = $"${data.Data.BestAskPrice.ToString("N2")}",
                    BidPrice = $"${data.Data.BestBidPrice.ToString("N2")}",

                };

            });

            socketClient.UnsubscribeAllAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to read the value from the first `Entry`, so I can perform the following calculation:

`BestAskPrice` x `HoldingsAmount`

Once that calculation has been done, it should constantly update the xaml view similar to how the websocket constantly the AskPrice and BidPrice in the view in realtime.

In other words, I have figured out how to get value from a websocket and display it in a xaml view, but I can';t seem to figure out how to get data from a xaml view, process it with data from a websocket, and then in realtime display the data in the xaml view.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to bind the entry to a property in your VM, just like you are doing with your Labels

Comment: @Jason, Should I be doing the calculation in the VM to calculate the `HoldingsValue`?

Comment: That's a perfectly logical place to do it.

Comment: @Jason,  Please see Update 1:  The HoldingsValue calculation works if I use a local HoldingsAmount value. How do I get it to take the value from the XAML HoldingsAmount Entry typed in by the user?  Updated code added.

Comment: you are doing the calculation in the VM constructor, so it happens **before** the user has had a chance to enter a value

Comment: So how do I do this which allows the `WebSocket` to constantly run and at the same time, allows the user to update the `HoldingsAmount` at anytime, giving a live view of the calculation for the `HoldingsValue`?

Comment: sorry, I misread what you are doing.  Your calculation is actually tied to an event.  So the **other** problem is that you are creating a new `Ticker` object each time, which will break your bindings.  You should just update the existing `Ticker` object instead.  You may also need to bind the `Entry` to a string property and convert it to a decimal when you do the calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using MVVM (you need to apply so many changes):

First you need to install nuget package CommunityToolkit.MVVM

Models: Ticker.cs

```
namespace MVVMDemo2.MVVM.Models
{
    public class Ticker
    {
        public string AskPrice { get; set; }
        public string BidPrice { get; set; }
        public string HoldingsValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Views: TickerView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MVVMDemo2.MVVM.Views.TickerView"
         Title="TickerView">

<VerticalStackLayout
    VerticalOptions="Center" 
    HorizontalOptions="Center">

    <Label 
    Text="Holdings"
    FontSize="25" />
    <Entry Placeholder="Enter holdings"
    BackgroundColor="Gray"
    Text="{Binding HoldingsAmount}"
    Keyboard="Numeric" />

        <Label 
    Text="Ask price"
    FontSize="25" />
        <Label 
    Text="{Binding Ticker.AskPrice}"
    FontSize="50" />

        <Label
    Text="Bid price"
    FontSize="25" />
        <Label 
    Text="{Binding Ticker.BidPrice}"
    FontSize="50" />

        <Label 
    Text="Holdings value"
    FontSize="25" />
        <Label 
    Text="{Binding Ticker.HoldingsValue}"
    FontSize="50" />

</VerticalStackLayout>
```

Views: TickerView.xaml.cs

```
using MVVMDemo2.MVVM.Models;
using MVVMDemo2.MVVM.ViewModels;

namespace MVVMDemo2.MVVM.Views;

public partial class TickerView : ContentPage
{
    public TickerView(TickerViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}
```

ViewModels: TickerViewModel.cs

```
using Binance.Net.Clients;
using Binance.Net.Objects;
using MVVMDemo2.MVVM.Models;
using PropertyChanged;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MVVMDemo2.MVVM.ViewModels
{
    
    public partial class TickerViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        public Ticker ticker;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public decimal holdingsAmount; 

        public TickerViewModel()
        {
            var socketClient = new BinanceSocketClient(new BinanceSocketClientOptions { });

        socketClient.SpotStreams.SubscribeToBookTickerUpdatesAsync("BTCUSDT", data => {

            Ticker = new Ticker
            {
                AskPrice = $"${data.Data.BestAskPrice.ToString("N2")}",
                BidPrice = $"${data.Data.BestBidPrice.ToString("N2")}",
                HoldingsValue = (HoldingsAmount * data.Data.BestBidPrice).ToString()
            };

        });

        socketClient.UnsubscribeAllAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation: using OBSERVABLE PROPERTIES you will be able to see the changed between your ui and apply them on the viewmodel. it's tested and got it working on my emulator:

[image: holding 0]
[image: holding 12]

i recommend you to follow [James Montemagno](https://www.youtube.com/c/JamesMontemagno) and [Gerald Versluis](https://www.youtube.com/c/GeraldVersluis) that explains everything on their videos about bindable properties, observable  objects/properties and everything about maui!

UPDATE if you get a blank page:

App.xaml.cs

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
```

AppShell.xaml:

```
<Shell
x:Class="MVVMDemo2.AppShell"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMDemo2.MVVM.Views">

<ShellContent 
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:TickerView}"
    Route="TickerView" /> 

</Shell>
```

AppShell.xaml.cs

```
public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(TickerView), typeof(TickerView));


    }
```

Comment: Not getting any errors, but getting a blank page.  Anything to do with `MainPage = new TickerView();` in `App.xaml.cs` ?

Comment: Did you use shell in your page? i will add an update at the bottom with the data you need!

Comment: @oshirowanen plz check update at bottom if you can't make it work i share to you a sample repo if you need! Other than that, I thank you for teaching me how to get value from a websocket and display it in a xaml view with live data, you always learn something when you want to help!

Comment: No problem at all for the websockets.  I have a huge amount to learn still!

Currently getting the error `'No parameterless constructor defined for type 'MVVMDemo2.MVVM.Views.TickerView'.'`

Comment: do you have the following on your maui program:
            builder.Services.AddTransient<TickerView>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<TickerViewModel>();
?

Comment: I don't have those in the program.  Where would those need to be added?  Assuming the View and the ViewModel.  I'll try it now.  Thanks.

Comment: It's the porpouse of DI working with MVVM! more info here! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xx1mve2AQr4

Comment: ` if you can't make it work i share to you a sample repo if you need!`  Could you please share that?  Thank you for the 3 links, I will be going through all those to learn more about MAUI, but for now, I just need to get the above program working.

Comment: https://github.com/LeanTolo/SampleRepo here is it! hope it helps! there may be different names in the views but it is the same logic

Comment: @oshirowanen If the problem is solved please consider marking the answer as correct, that would help me a lot

Comment: I am about to try out your git solution now and will let you know how i get on before the end of the weekend.  Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: Tested and working!

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the property in your ViewModel same as the labels
Kindly go through this for more in-depth info

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/getting-data-from-view-to-controller-in-mvc/